# Using join in place of this sub-query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I have a table by the following structure and records, All i want to do is to just extract orderid of those records whose status id is either 1 or 2 , i want to exclude all orderid with statusid=3 , , problem is that orderid 106 has both status 1 and 3 ...
I have written a sub-query which serves the purpose..

```
select * 
from orders_status_history 
where orders_id NOT IN 
   (select orders_id 
    from orders_status_history 
    where orders_status_id = 3)
```

is there any other way of doing this without using sub-queries as i have heard it hampers performance. As my query can return thousands of rows as well.

```
id    order-id    status-id
1     1            1
2     2            1
3     105          1
4     106          1
5     106          3
6     108          1
7     109          1
8     109          2
```

Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated ..Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may do that:

```
SELECT  osh.*
FROM    orders_status_history osh
LEFT JOIN
        orders_status_history oshd
ON      oshd.orders_id = osh_orders_id
        AND oshd.orders_status_id = 3
WHERE   oshd.orders_id IS NULL
```

However, if you have an index on `order_status_history (orders_id, orders_status_id)`, then the `NOT IN` query is just as fine.

You may want to read this:

- [**NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: MySQL**](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

Comment: Thnx a lot sir.. It did the trick for me... All i can say is Thnx Thnx Thnx Thnx

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you use sub query while you can use the following query

```
select orders_id from orders_status_history where orders_status_id <> 3
```

Please try this , and I hope it helps

Comment: Thnx but it doesn't work out as it returns all the records , except for the record where statusid is 3 , but one record has both statusid i.e. 106 has 1 and 3 both....

Comment: try to join two tables; <br/>select osh1.orders_id from orders_status_history osh1 join orders_status_history osh2 on osh1.order_id = osh2.order_id where orders_status_id <> 3